# can anyone identify this plant please?

Tags: species-identification, species

Seen in the med and have it in my garden
[image]

Comment: Please specify where you are located in the world, and if this plant was acquired locally or not. :)

Comment: It is a houseplant, not a common wild plant. Your question might be a better fit on [gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: This flower is some type of mandevilla.

Comment: The question states "seen in the med" which I assume means the Mediterranean.

Answer (score 2):

This is a climbing plant from the Genus [*Mandevilla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandevilla). It's a genus native to the Americas.

Here is a photo for comparisson:

[image]

However, since the Genus *Mandevilla* has more than 150 species (let alone cultivar and hybrids), narrowing it down to a particular species may be very difficult in your case.